# Custom Tool Error: after switching project from .net 4.5 to .Net 4.6.1

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.5, service-reference, .net-4.6.1

I have upgraded my project from .Net 4.5 to .Net 4.6.1 and am now getting the following errors when trying to compile:

> The "GenerateBindingRedirects" task failed unexpectedly.
>   System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>      at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.GenerateBindingRedirects.UpdateExistingBindingRedirects(XElement runtimeNode, IDictionary`2 redirects)
>      at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.GenerateBindingRedirects.Execute()
>      at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
>      at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__26.MoveNext()
>
> Custom tool error: Failed to generate file: An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for system.serviceModel/bindings: The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG)) (C:\ALM[BranchName]\Common[ProjectName]\app.config line 48)   Portal.Interface    C:\ALM[BranchName]\Common[ProjectName]\Service References[ServiceName]\Reference.svcmap

Based on other searches, I've tried:
Removing the ServiceModel section in app config and updating service references.
This doesn't work though, because I do not have access to the services from my machine.

I've also confirmed that the service references are configured with "Reuse types in referenced assemblies" is unchecked.

One search led me to removing one of the entries in Reference.svcmap, but was non-specific on what entry should be removed.

I'm definitely out of my element with service references so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, "unexpected" is a pretty accurate description.  I suspect you'll have to tell us a lot more about your project before anybody can formulate a theory on how an app.config file could affect MSBuild.

Comment: If your feeling adventurous, you can look into the [source code](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/blob/master/src/XMakeTasks/AssemblyDependency/GenerateBindingRedirects.cs#L187) to see what *could* be the problem with your project file. There are a couple of things to that could cause the NRE, but one likely possibility is, that some expected XML attributes are not present in your project file where they should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The offending line:

```
private void UpdateExistingBindingRedirects(XElement runtimeNode, IDictionary<AssemblyName, string> redirects)
{    
    ...
    var publicKeyToken = assemblyIdentity.Attribute("publicKeyToken");
    var publicKeyTokenValue = publicKeyToken.Value;
    ...
```

looks like you cannot redirect assemblies that are not strong-named.  which means I should just be able to remove the entries.  This does make me wonder how this worked before in .Net 4.5

Comment: I ended up deleting these redirects as they were useless to begin with.  I talked with the original developer who put them in and he couldn't remember why he did it.

Comment: Check you bindings in your app.config.
I has some duplicates. After removing those it worked again.

Answer (score 0):

Specifying `publicKeyToken="null"` fixes it for me.